# Can you to retrieve the APK key if you have all the source code

Tags: android

I realized I don't have the key for updating my android app. Is there a way to obtain the key that I used if I have both the APK and the source code? I also have the password.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the keystore back and hence, cannot update the application. You have to add a new application.